# How to use DRF auth on Django non-REST views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I would like to use my current Django views in another project (which lives on another domain), so I will need token authentication.

Is it possible to use Django Rest Framework, which has a good token authentication system, to authenticate users on Django non-REST views?

I currently use the `login_required` decorator which doesn't work for Django Rest Framework token auth:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
```